# Javascript Scope problem with OAuth

Tags: javascript, oauth

I was wondering how to call `waitForPin` in this line:

```
setTimeout(this.waitForPin, 100);
```

File:

```
// namespace our code
window.App = {};

// my class (no Class.create in JQuery so code in native JS)
App.Something = function() {
};

// add functions to the prototype
App.Something.prototype = {

    // automatically called
    initialize: function(name, sound) {

        this.wnd;

        this.config = {
            // some vars
        };

        this.oauth = new OAuth(this.config);

        // attach event handlers, binding to 'this' object
        $("#request_token").click($.proxy(this.request_token, this));

    },

    request_token: function() {
        this.oauth.fetchRequestToken(this.openAuthoriseWindow, this.failureHandler);
    },

    openAuthoriseWindow: function (url) {
        this.wnd = window.open(url, 'authorise');
        setTimeout(this.waitForPin, 100); // how to call waitForPin here?
    },

    waitForPin : function (scope) {
        // do sth
    }

};
```

Comment: What's the problem, this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(window.App.Something.waitForPin(scope), 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `waitForPin` function is attached to the prototype of `Something`.  In order to access it create an instance of `Something` and call the method on that instance.  Example

```
setTimeout((new App.Something()).waitForPin, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(this.waitForPin, 100);
```

That's the correct way to do it.

```
var Q = new App.Something;
Q.openAuthoriseWindow();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bBRPv/

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
setTimeout($.proxy(this.waitForPin, this), 100);
```